# Question about write number in JLabel in Java?

Tags: java

How can I print number in any component like JLabel with certain number of sapces

such as 
if I write :

```
double num = 123567; 
label.setext(" number " + num + "is big") ; == > number 123567isbig

double num = 12; 
label.setext(" number " + num + "is big") ; == > number 12     isbig
```

the number "num" is writen on 6 spaces in the both statment ..

How can I do that in Java ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String formatNumber(int n) {
  return String.format("%-12d", n);
}

label.setText(" number " + formatNumber(1234567) + "is big");
```

Comment: It's harder when you've got a `double` though... everything I've tried wants to include ".0" or ".000000" etc.

Comment: Heh, I blissfully ignored that. My solution would be to either assign or cast the `double` to an `int` as a first step.

Comment: thanks Mr.Carl, your first answer works , I want double , int doesn't work .


Mr.Jon Skeet : I have variable and it take it's value from some operator , so I can't add 00000 to it .